# App doesn't work with ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, android-viewholder

I have this problem with my ImageAdapter in Android Studio. I have huge performance problems when I start the application on a phone. So, people suggested, I should use a ViewHolder. I looked at dozens of examples on how others did it. tried lot's of versions. Still, my app crashes when I try to open that activity. Here's my code:

```
public class ImageAdap extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdap(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null; //mThumbIds[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = new ImageView(mContext);
        vi.setTag(holder);        //Here is the point the app crashes
    }
    else  {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    holder.image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(800, 600));
    holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    holder.image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    holder.image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return vi;
}

// references to my images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sampleda_01,
        R.drawable.sampleda_02,
        R.drawable.sampleda_03,
        R.drawable.sampleda_04,
        R.drawable.sampleda_05
}; }
```

The program complies without any problem. But it crashes, when I open the activity. So I used debugger to see, when the app crashes. The app crashes, when

```
vi.setTag(holder);
```

should be performed. I appreciate every kind of help.

logcat:

> --------- beginning of crash 07-21 13:42:19.229 3059-3059/com.b.a.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.b.a.test, PID: 3059
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.View.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.b.a.test.ImageAdap.getView(ImageAdap.java:59)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 07-21
>   13:42:21.620 3059-3059/com.b.a.test I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 3059 SIG: 9 07-21 13:42:22.939
>   3315-3315/com.b.a.test W/System: ClassLoader referenced
>   unknown path: /data/app/com.b.a.test-1/lib/x86 07-21
>   13:42:23.815 3315-3315/com.b.a.test W/art: Before
>   Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 07-21 13:42:23.971
>   3315-3348/com.b.a.test D/OpenGLRenderer: Use
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
>
> ```
>                                                                        [ 07-21 13:42:24.003  3315: 3315 D/         ]
>                                                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad1b97e0, tid
> ```
>
> 3315

Comment: and what does the crash say? I dont see anywhere where you inflate your view for the row

Comment: give your logcat output please

Comment: @tyczj Unfortunately the app crashed ... sorry that I don't know how to see the reasons of the crash. But like I said, I used debugger and he crashes when he tries to perform: vi.setTag(holder);

Comment: look at the logcat

Comment: @Kushan can you first tell me how I access it? :D

Comment: which environment are you developping with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: first connect your phone to the pc in usb debugging mode. Then use ALT+ 6 to bring up logcat. Run the app and you will see a full stack trace of Exceptions

Comment: @tyczj ,I put in the logcat as far as I think this one should be right

Comment: @Kushan same as one above

Comment: @user3793589 I use Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should look like this

```
if(convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    vi = imageView;
    holder.image = imageView
    vi.setTag(holder); 
}
```

You need to set the view first

Comment: Wow, great now it works. But is it just me, or why isn't the performance better than before? At least, I have the feeling regarding the virtual machine. I will try on a real device now

Comment: before what? I would think performance would be better now since it was not even working before

Comment: Before I used a Viewholder. The problem I have is, that it works smoothly on tablets but slowly on phones. Even same with virtual devices.

Comment: its the image you are putting into the imageview

Comment: but they have 800x600 resolution with max 90kb

Comment: yeah it takes time to put larger images into memory, you should probably read this https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
if(convertView == null)
```

You should inflate layout when that assertion is true. Because your view is null. Like that;

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
```

If you don't want to inflate a layout you can use like that.

```
View vi = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;

if(convertView == null) {
    vi = new ImageView(mContext);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.image =(ImageView) vi;
    vi.setTag(holder);        //Here is the point the app crashes
}
```

Comment: He create view dynamically and not inflate it from xml - `        holder.image = new ImageView(mContext);`

Comment: Ok you can set  like that ```convertView = new ImageView();``` because your convertView return null always like that implementation and like View vi.  If you use ```ViewHolder``` you can cast ```convertView``` to ```ImageView``` and set ```holder.image```. I changed my sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
View vi = convertView;

if(convertView == null) {
    vi.setTag(holder); 
}
```

Just check your code carefully. Simply saying you invoke `setTag` from null, and `NullPointerException` throws because of that.

Comment: He's doing the correct thing. If its null, hes creating a viewholder else using the one which came with the recycled one

Comment: If it's null, then `vi` is also null.

Comment: yea he should inflate a view, but your answer doesnt do that which is why i downvoted it